# Regular expression required for replacing string in shell script

Tags: regex, linux, shell

Can anyone please help me write a shell script in linux which would replace the hostname in a particular file.

eg : I have multiple files which have certain ip addresses.

```
http://10.160.228.12:8001/soa-infra/services/default/AIAAsyncErrorHandlingBPELProcess/client?WSDL

http://VQAIAAPPDEV:8001/soa-infra/services/default/AIAAsyncErrorHandlingBPELProcess/client?WSDL
```

Basically what I would want to replace is the string between "http://" and ":8001" with any required string.

Can someone help me with this please.

Some More info:-

I want to do this iteratively across many folders. So basically it will search all the files in each folder and perform the necessary changes.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `sed`.  Saying:

```
sed -r 's|(http://)([^:]*)(:8001)|\1something\3|g' filename
```

would replace is the string between "http://" and ":8001" with `something`.

If you want to make the change to the file in-place, use the `-i` option:

```
sed -i -r 's|(http://)([^:]*)(:8001)|\1something\3|g' filename
```

Comment: What if I want to iteratively check in files in many folders and do the necessary changes?

Comment: @user3056318 Use `find`.  You can say:  `find /some/path -type f -exec sed -i -r 's|(http://)([^:]*)(:8001)|\1something\3|g' {} \;`

Comment: @user3056318 Consider [accepting the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if it worked for you.  You might also want to refer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0):

Use sed command from Linux shell

sed -i 's%OldHost%NewHost%g' /yourfolder/yourfile

Answer (score 0):

Tried with "for"

```
 # cat replace.txt
 http://10.160.228.12:8001/soa-     infra/services/default/AIAAsyncErrorHandlingBPELProcess/client?WSDL

 http://VQAIAAPPDEV:8001/soa-infra/services/default/AIAAsyncErrorHandlingBPELProcess/client?WSDL


 # for i in `cat replace.txt | awk -F: '{print $2}' | sed 's/^\/\///g' | sed '/^$/d'` ; do sed -i "s/$i/Your_hostname/"  replace.txt ; done

 # cat replace.txt
 http://Your_hostname:8001/soa- infra/services/default/AIAAsyncErrorHandlingBPELProcess/client?WSDL

 http://Your_hostname:8001/soa-infra/services/default/AIAAsyncErrorHandlingBPELProcess/client?WSDL
```

Its working for me...!